# Prevent input device to submit angularjs form

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I'm developing an application where an input text field will get populated by a scanner scanning in a barcode.

The problem is that when the scanner scans, it submits the form. It can't be disabled on the scanner, so I need to disable it on the form self. I was thinking about:

```
<form onsubmit="this.preventDefault()">
```

Is that the way to prevent the auto submission?

My form looks like:

```
    <form name="form" novalidate>

                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-success': form.barcode.$valid, 'has-error': form.barcode.$invalid && form.barcode.$dirty}">
                                <label for="barcode" class="control-label">Barcode:</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="view.asset.barcode" name="barcode" ng-required="true" id="barcode" class="form-control" ng-change="validateBarcodeUnique(form)">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i ng-class="{'icon-ok': form.barcode.$valid, 'icon-remove': form.barcode.$invalid && form.barcode.$dirty}"></i> </span>
                                </div>
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <span ng-show="form.barcode.$error.required && form.barcode.$dirty">Barcode is required!</span>
                                    <span ng-show="form.barcode.$error.pattern && form.barcode.$dirty">Barcode is already used!</span>


                    </span>
                        </div>
...
                        <div>
                            <button ng-click="form.$setPristine(); updateAsset();" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || form.$pristine" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                            <a ng-click="view.asset = null;" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a ng-show="assets.length > 1" ng-click="getPicSingle()" class="btn btn-primary">Take specific picture</a>
                                <a ng-show="view.asset.image_specific" ng-click="removePicSingle()" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

PS: how do I fix the indenting of pasted code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change button type from "submit" to "button" and it will prevent auto submission.